# Not able to inspect element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am writing script using selenium (java). But with Internet Explorer I am not able to Inspect element. Can someone help me its very urgent.

Thanks and regards,
Kiran Raghuwanshi

Comment: why are you trying with IE browser?
use Mozilla FF browser add add-ons Firebug and Firepath to find x-path and for inspecting element.

If you are trying with IE browser Press f12 button to inspect element.

Comment: Can you right-click and inspect?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider use Firefox browser along with its Firebug plugin, together they will make your job much easier.

> P.S. IE is phasing out of the market by Microsoft, why are you using it?

Here, this tutorial is extremely good. [Firebug tutorial link](http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/firebug-tutorials.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect/identify element by 2 way -

1. As suggested by @Yu Zhang, Install Firefox browser plugin like Firebug and Firepath.
   Press F12 (Function key) to launch firebug/firepath.
2. Using selenium IDE - By pressing 'Select' or 'Find' button you can also highlight the element.